# Sweetalert2: ¿Hay alguna manera de obtener los datos del paso anterior y usarlos en el siguiente paso?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

### ¿Hay alguna manera de obtener los datos del paso anterior y usarlos en el siguiente paso?

---

Quiero obtener el valor del primer paso y usarlo en el segundo paso para hacer un llamada ajax o fetch y usarlos datos devueltos en el segundo select, al finalizar usar los tres valores en otra petición ajax o fetch.

---

*Algo similar al siguiente Ejemplo sweetalert2:*

```js
queue = async() => {
  const data1 = '';
  const {
    value: formValues
  } = await Swal.mixin({
    confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
    showCancelButton: true,
    progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
  }).queue([{
      title: 'Question 1',
      text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy',
      input: 'select',
      inputOptions: {
        apples: 'Apples',
        bananas: 'Bananas',
        grapes: 'Grapes',
        oranges: 'Oranges'
      },
      inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
      showCancelButton: true,
      inputValidator: (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (value != '') {
            resolve()
          } else {
            resolve('You need to select:)')
          }
        })
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Question 2',
      text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy',
      input: 'select',
      inputOptions: {
        apples: 'Apples',
        bananas: 'Bananas',
        grapes: 'Grapes',
        oranges: 'Oranges'
      },
      inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
      showCancelButton: true,
      inputValidator: (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (value != '') {
            resolve()
          } else {
            resolve('You need to select:)')
          }
        })
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Question 3',
      text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy',
      input: 'select',
      inputOptions: {
        apples: 'Apples',
        bananas: 'Bananas',
        grapes: 'Grapes',
        oranges: 'Oranges'
      },
      inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
      showCancelButton: true,
      inputValidator: (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (value != '') {
            resolve()
          } else {
            resolve('You need to select:)')
          }
        })
      }
    }
  ]).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      const answers = JSON.stringify(result.value)
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'All done!',
        html: `
            Your answers:
            <pre><code>${answers}</code></pre>
          `,
        confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
      })
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<h1>sweetalert2 queue!</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="queue();">Info</button>
```

[Encontré algo similar pero no me queda muy claro en este link](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/539)

---

Quiero obtener el valor del primer paso y usarlo en el segundo paso para hacer un llamada ajax o fetch y usarlos datos devueltos en el segundo select, al finalizar usar los tres valores en otra petición ajax o fetch.

---

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que usar una Dynamic queue, usando preConfirm en cada fase del modal puedes usar `Swal.insertQueueStep` para agregar una fase al final de la cola y hacerlas dinamicamente con el valor de la fase anterior

```js
queue = async() => {
  const data1 = '';
  const { value: formValues } = await Swal.mixin({
    confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
    showCancelButton: true,
    progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
  }).queue([
    step1()
  ]).then((result) => {
    console.log('end of queue')
  })
}

function step1(){
  return {
    title: 'Question 1',
    text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy',
    input: 'select',
    inputOptions: {
      apples: 'Apples',
      bananas: 'Bananas',
      grapes: 'Grapes',
      oranges: 'Oranges'
    },
    inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
    showCancelButton: true,
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (value != '') {
          resolve()
        } else {
          resolve('You need to select:)')
        }
      })
    },
    preConfirm: (result) => {
       Swal.insertQueueStep(step2(result))
    }
  }
}

function step2(fruit){
  return {
    title: 'Question 2',
    text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy, previous value: '+ fruit,
    input: 'select',
    inputOptions: {
      apples: 'Apples',
      bananas: 'Bananas',
      grapes: 'Grapes',
      oranges: 'Oranges'
    },
    inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
    showCancelButton: true,
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (value != '') {
          resolve()
        } else {
          resolve('You need to select:)')
        }
      })
    },
    preConfirm: (result) => {
       Swal.insertQueueStep(step3(fruit, result))
    }
  }
}

function step3(fruit1, fruit2){
  return {
    title: 'Question 3',
    text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy, previous values: '+fruit1+', '+fruit2,
    input: 'select',
    inputOptions: {
      apples: 'Apples',
      bananas: 'Bananas',
      grapes: 'Grapes',
      oranges: 'Oranges'
    },
    inputPlaceholder: 'Select a fruit',
    showCancelButton: true,
    inputValidator: (value) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (value != '') {
          resolve()
        } else {
          resolve('You need to select:)')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<h1>sweetalert2 queue!</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="queue();">Info</button>
```